# Updating a table image using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

I have run into a funny situation with using AJAX to update databases.

On my table that is editable, you can upload images. Once you modify the table (New or Edit), the fields are sent and the table is reloaded with AJAX. The images are uploaded to a folder and their filename/path is captured to show on the table. This is OK for really small images (size) but for any larger image, the table reloads faster than the image was uploaded. So you end up with a broken image on the table that requires a full page reload.

I was wondering if there was an AJAX solution to constantly try to load an image on the screen (based on a class name) until it loads or time out after a certain amount.

Thanks.

Comment: How are the fields sent? Can't you just wait to reload the table until you get a result?

Comment: No... the problem is the table API I am using. I only send the form to upload the image when the table API is sending over all of the other fields and I don't have control to tell it to wait.